# How to move to the page entered in the form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, frontend

let me start by saying that I'm a freshman. I would like to create a form with a button that, when pressed, will generate a page written in an inputa. How to do it? example:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <!-- a hidden input -->
  <input type="hidden" name="a_hidden_input"/>
  
  <!-- a text input -->
  <input type="text" name="a_text_input"/>

  <!-- submit button -->
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "written in the form's input"?

Comment: You need backend programming like php or python or nodejs that will create a file, put dummy contents and create a page (basically a file) on your server, and route will be published to your server.

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation of what you want to achieve and an example of code that you tried but didn't work. Also please read: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic example for getting your data and displaying in the page  .

```
<head>
    <script>
        function generate() {
            debugger
            var strText = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
            var strText1 = document.getElementById("txtEmail").value;
            document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = strText;
            document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = strText1;
            window.location.href = "http://mywebsite.com/home.html";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="Name" id="txtName" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="text" name="Email" id="txtEmail" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="button" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit" onclick="generate()">
    </form>
    <div>
        <h1>New Page</h1>
        <p id="p1"></p>
        <p id="p2"></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

If u use any library like react js or framework like angular with backend technologies like php,nodejs, with databases as sql , mongodb or firebase  it will be super easy for u .